# AntiforgeryToken & many forms perf

Tags: c#, asp.net, antiforgerytoken

I want to make content in which the delete links are secure. ie.

Row 1

edit  delete

Row 2

edit  delete

where the delete links are POST links.

To make the delete links POST requests instead of get requests, I'm able to do this with a simple form post paired with an AntiForgeryToken and AntiForgeryToken validation

```
   using(Html.BeginForm("Delete","Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
            @Html.Hidden("objectId", i)
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
    }
```

c#

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Delete(int objectId)
 {
      SafeLogic();
      return View(...);
 }
```

---

I also would like to do this with tables, but I have some performance concerns over the generation of so many tokens, eg.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
  <tr>
  <td> Data Row @i </td>
  <td>    
    using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
            @Html.Hidden("objectId", i)

            <input type="image" src="img_delete.gif" alt="Delete" />
    }
  </td>
 
}
```

How costly is the generation of AntiForgeryTokens? Is the generation of many AntiForgery tokens eg. up to 100, going to be a problem. It is okay to have this many inline html forms?

Comment: I'd look at what @Josh represents below - with jQuery calls the page feels more modern. Even if you do posts, the form there would require the user to reload the whole page or frame.

Comment: I too want to know the answer, and it annoys me when everyone just adds javascript to do things that could perfectly well be done without. It just adds needless complexity and fragility. (Not that I'm against slick websites that make good use of javascript, but it's just this default answer that gets on my nerves.) None of the answers below so far actually answer the question directly.

Comment: Too bad the accepted answer doesn't answer the question about cost/performance of high numbers of antiforgerytokens :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a personal project that needed something like you're doing.

Instead of having a form for each item that could be removed, I had a single form with a single anti-forgery token.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  {your HTML/Razor}
}
```

The delete icon was basically an ajax call that would activate the controller action...

```
public JsonResult Delete(int id)
{
   //delete the item
   if(success)
   {
      return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
   }
   else
   {
      return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
   }
}
```

...and that action would return true or false (success or failure).  Acting on that information, I would use jQuery to remove the item from the table (in my case, a  formatted table listing).  That way I wasn't refreshing the entire page.

May not work for your implementation but worked out for me.

I don't necessarily know which is best practice, multiple forms or a single with multiple submit buttons.  Some say that you shouldn't do multiple forms if the end action for those forms point to the same action.  More info: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=html+best+practices+multiple+forms

It might come down to how pretty or readable you want your html (makes for easier debugging), for instance, if you have a page with a couple of  blocks, it probably won't be all that messy.  However, think of how your page will be once you have five, or six such blocks.

Comment: I think using jquery & ajax is technically the correct approach for forcing post actions - since it avoids a page reresh - so I guess I'll mark as answer. In some sense though inline forms allow me to sidestep building into a javascript framework to handle simple actions.

Comment: @user1778606 I used to think the same thing.  Recently, though, I have found that javascript adds a lot of functionality with very low overhead compared to making static pages.  It also looks cleaner, for the client, because it's all happening in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the token outside of the loop to sidestep any rending perf things. I'm still not sure many inline forms is a great solution or even better than attaching scripts or onclick events. Just trying things out.

```
@{var token = @Html.AntiForgeryToken();}


@for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{


  using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Home", FormMethod.Post))
  {
          @Html.Hidden("text", "Element:" + i)
          @token
          <input type="Submit"/>
  }
}
```